# InvocationTargetException while calling getParameter() in JApplet

Tags: java, applet, invocationtargetexception

I've got a JApplet in Java 7 and everytime I want to start it inside my browser I get an `InvocationTargetException` at the call of `getParameter()` from `JApplet`. Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDTAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.OldPluginAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.applet.Applet.getParameter(Unknown Source)
    at TicTacToe.TicTacToeAppletView.<init>(TicTacToeAppletView.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My HTML File looks like this:

```
<applet code="TicTacToe/TicTacToeAppletView.class" width="400" height="400">
<param name=Size value="4">
</applet>
```

In the same folder as the HTML File there is a folder named TicTacToe which contains all the necessary class files (of course, otherwise I'd get a `ClassNotFoundException`).

It works fine if I don't use getParameter(). The Java code using this method simply looks like:

```
String s = getParameter("Size");
```

So what the hell is causing so much trouble?

Comment: can you paste the code of the Java Class corresponding to this `StackTraceElement`? `at TicTacToe.TicTacToeAppletView.<init>(TicTacToeAppletView.java:34)`

Comment: I did, it's the line `String s = getParameter("Size");`

Comment: 1) What version does [Test VM](http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp) report for the testing browser? 2) Be sure to validate the HTML.  To work with an applet tag, it will need to be HTML 3.2 or HTML 4.01 Transitional.  Or better still, write the applet element using `deployJava.js`, mentioned in the info. page on [tag:applet].

Comment: Well... I guess my problem is solved. In my example there was still a `main()` method and a constructor in which getParameter was called and no `JApplet` method such as `init()` (it's actually not mine, so I didn't came up with the idea to verify that there is an `init()` method). But now I'm still wondering why it works if I don't use the `getParameter()` method but the class contains a `main()` method (and the constructor). Looks like the `main()` is called, but why?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the parameter name, Size, be in quotes?

```
<param name="Size" value="4">
```

For more on using parameters please check out the [Defining and Using Applet Parameters Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html)

Comment: No it mustn't...or needn't... either way, without quotes should work! (compare with [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))). Besides, with quotes or even after dropping the whole param tag I still get the same error.

Comment: @MichelMichaelMeyer: Are you calling your applet inside of a try/catch block? Are you launching it on the event dispatch thread as per the applet tutorials?